# Jersey REST The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

Although this is one ancient question, I still can not find the answer to make this work.
Please correct if you find any of my statement is not correct.

I have a Java Face app and use REST for the Web Services.  I don't think Face has anything to do with my problem at all.
The web.xml is:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>NDREST</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.bi.nd.webservice</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NDREST</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/nd/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have quite a few more servlets in the web.xml since is is a Face app with Trinidad, etc.

In the package com.bi.nd.webservice, my resource class is:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("/hello")
public class TransactionResource 
{
public TransactionResource() 
{
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String itWorks()
{
    return "Get is OK";
}
}
```

The fact that my class has a @GET is enough to identify itself a resource class.
Let alone all other complexities, I compiled my source code with Ant in Eclipse and I got this error in the catalina.out file:

```
May 24, 2011 8:48:46 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
     com.bi.nd.webservice
May 24, 2011 8:48:46 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.7 05/20/2011 11:04 AM'
May 24, 2011 8:48:46 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules <init>
SEVERE: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
```

Some suggested that copy the asm.jar, jsr-api.jar, jersey-server.jar and jersey-core.jar into the app WEB-INF/lib.  I did that and it still did not work. 
I found the suggestion was a bit odd since WEB-INF/lib is a place where Eclipse will install all dependency libraries from the build path.  It is not a place where we manually put libraries.

Some explained that this error had something to do with Java plug-in and the way Jersey was written.  But that was years ago.

Can some one explains to me why I keep having this problem?

Followup:
Although from REST web site, resource class defined as Root resource classes are POJOs (Plain Old Java Objects) that are either annotated with@Path or have at least one method annotated with @Path or a request method designator such as @GET, @PUT, @POST, or @DELETE. Resource methods are methods of a resource class annotated with a request method designator. This section describes how to use Jersey to annotate Java objects to create RESTful web services.

I have to add @Path("/hello") to my class, and suddenly Jersey can find my resource class

Now the catalina.out file looks like:

```
May 24, 2011 3:13:02 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
com.bi.nd.webservice
May 24, 2011 3:13:02 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
class com.bi.nd.webservice.TransactionResource
May 24, 2011 3:13:02 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
May 24, 2011 3:13:02 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.7 05/20/2011 11:04 AM'
```

But the problem is far from over.  I try to access the URL `http://localhost:8080/nd/hello` and I still get the 404 NOT FOUND.  Is the Provider class NOT FOUND an important message?

Comment: Can you share what problem you fixed? I am having the same issue! I keep getting a 404 even though I have been over everything with a fine tooth comb

Comment: @user759646 facing the same problem,  i am running it in weblogic

Answer (score 11):

I had the same error message and solved it by modifying my web.xml file. Make sure it has this in it:

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
   <param-value>your.package.name.here</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: that did not work for me... even after adding this in my web.xml, error persists

Answer (score 7):

I found another reason Jersey could fail to find a root resource. The error message is the same, so I thought it'd be a good reason to document the root cause here in case other people stumble on it.

I have a root resource class that has the following annotations on it:

```
@Singleton
@Path("/helloWorld")
@Service(...) // my own custom annotation
public class MyRootResource {
...
}
```

This will cause the root resource scanning within Jersey to fail.

The fix is to change the order of the annotations:

```
@Service(...) // my own custom annotation
@Singleton
@Path("/helloWorld")
public class MyRootResource {
...
}
```

This works.

Comment: Worked for me, I was using @RequestMapping(value = "/api"), then changed by  @Path("/api")

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, note that having @GET on a class is not enough to identify it as a root resource class; the class must have an @Path on it. Yours does, so that's not the problem.

I was having the same problem as you: it worked in Eclipse, but then didn't work when I built it for external use.

I'm using embedded Jetty, with a main() that looks like this:

```
public static void main(String argv[])
{
    try
    {
        // from http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        contextHandler.setContextPath("/");
        server.setHandler(contextHandler);

        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670363/how-do-i-programmatically-configure-jersey-to-use-jackson-for-json-deserializa
        final PackagesResourceConfig prc = new PackagesResourceConfig("com.ultimatefoodfight.server.api");
        final Map<String, Object> prcProperties = prc.getProperties();
        prcProperties.put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, true);

        // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421574/embedded-jetty-with-jersey-or-resteasy
        contextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(prc)), "/*");

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

(When embedding Jetty, this takes the place of a web.xml.) com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig scans the named classes for root resource provider classes -- I'm sure the web.xml is just pointing at the same. This worked fine in Eclipse. Server startup correctly reports this in the console:

```
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.ultimatefoodfight.server.api
Jul 29, 2012 7:31:28 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class com.ultimatefoodfight.server.api.Users
  class com.ultimatefoodfight.server.api.Contests
```

However, when I start the application on a server, I only get the first two lines of that, and no Root resource classes are found.

It turns out that when you make a jar, there are different options for how it is constructed; in particular, if you just make it by listing the paths to the classes, you get
just those entries. But if you point jar at the directory with a wild card, you also get all the intermediate paths. See this message for the example that tipped me off: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/neo4j/0dNqGXvEbNg/xaNlRiU1cHMJ .

The PackagesResourceConfig class depends on having a directory with the name of the package in order to find the classes within it. I went back to Eclipse, and found an option at the bottom of the "Export ... > Jar" dialog for "Add directory entries." I turned that on, exported the jar again, and then the scanning found my resource classes. You'll need to find some comparable option in your build environment.

Comment: Hey Chris! Thanks a lot for your post. I was sick of jersey because sometimes it used to detect my root resources and sometimes it didnt. I didnt know what the problem was and your post pointed to the exact problem and helped me resolve it. Thanks a lot, again!

Answer (score 3):

I've just spent a good 5 or 6 hours wrestling with this too and have finally fixed the problem. This may work for you too perhaps.

The source code I've been using is available at [Lars Vogel's tutorial page](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html). Using Apache Tomcat 6.0.20, asm-all-3.3.1.jar, jersey-bundle-1.17.1.jar and jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar I was getting the same results as the OP, i.e.

```
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class com.mypackage.MyClass
13/03/2013 4:32:30 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
```

I had the following settings across the various deployment files:

```
context root = rivets
<url-pattern>/rest</url-pattern>
@Path("/hello")
```

Trying to access the resource using the following URL gave a 404 error

```
 http://localhost:8080/rivets/rest/hello
```

I was *eventually* able to fix it by changing the url-pattern to :

```
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
```

Though I'm not sure how this will hold up when I start to introduce more complex resources. Anyway, hopefully this may help someone.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the "no provider classes found" message is scary but not important.

"The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes" is a much bigger problem.

I found that the resource class needs to be annotated with @Path, and the provider class (if you have one -- we use one for mapping exceptions to HTTP response codes) needs to be annotated with @Provider, and both need to be in the right package, and then Jersey will find them.

Answer (score 1):

you might need to use a url like this

```
http://localhost:8080/<web_context_root>/nd/hello
```

Comment: or we can change the Web_Context_Root in the server.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

So I read trough the answers and still had the same problem. I resolved it as follows.

Added "jetty-web.xml" to the "WEB-INF" folder. Thus:
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml

The content of the jetty-web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath">/YourEndpoint</Set>
</Configure>
```

My rest is now available at:

```
http://localhost:8080/YourEndpoint/webresources/someMethod
```

Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: This is due to i forget to defing the endpoint in web.xml

Comment: <context-param>
  <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
  <param-value>/rest</param-value>
 </context-param>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Solved it by fixing in the web.xml the param-value under init-param tag.
By default, Eclipse had set in the web.xml the name of the project into display-name. That shall not be copied to the **param-value**, but the Java package.

```
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.test.demo</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem, please verify your class MapperIn, there is required to specify Path:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.OPTIONS;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.lot.account.api.doc.GetMemberAccountsIn;
import com.lot.common.doc.CommonApi;
import com.lot.common.doc.FlowData;
import com.lot.security.authorization.RequestData;


@Path("/account/member/")
public class MapperIn {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/{memberId}")
    public GetAccountIn prepareGetAccount(@PathParam("memberId") String memberId) {

        // create apiInput
        GetAccountIn apiInput = new GetAccountIn ();

        // map values from url
            apiInput.setMemberId(memberId);


        return apiInput;
    }
//...
}
```