# Java Jersey Rest : No provider classes found. (404 error when accessing URL)

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, rest, jersey

> **Edit:** I hadn't realized that all request were first going into "Apache" and then were redirected to Tomcat. I added a new redirection in the `apache2.conf` file. See the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6597100) for details.

I am having the exact same problem as this question.
[Jersey REST The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111074/jersey-rest-the-resourceconfig-instance-does-not-contain-any-root-resource-classe)
However the user never answered the question.

I am using Tomcat, without maven. I followed this tutorial.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-tomcat/index.html

I made changes to web.xml as per the article
i.e the new servlet and servlet mapping was created with the correct package name.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
  com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>sample.hello.resources</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have deployed the following jars to tomcat

```
asm.jar
jersey-server.jar
jersey-core.jar
jsr311.jar
```

The tomcat startup log has the following exceptions.

```
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
    INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
      sample.hello.resources

   com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
    INFO: Root resource classes found:
      class sample.hello.resources.HelloResource

   com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
    INFO: No provider classes found.

   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
    INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.8 06/24/2011 12:17 PM'
```

When I access the URL I get a 404.
http://localhost:8080/Jersey/rest/hello

The code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
    }
}
```

I do not see any other exceptions in the logs

Comment: It would help if you posted the web.xml and the sample.hello.resources.HelloResource class as well.

Comment: Those don't look like exceptions to me in your log, just informational messages. That IBM tutorial says something about creating a web app named Jersey using Eclipse. I'm not familiar with deploying to Tomcat via Eclipse, but are you certain that Jersey is the right deployment path? That is, have you tried browsing to http://localhost:8080/rest/hello ?

Comment: The context path is without changing it like the Eclipse project name. You can investigate this easily by drill down the projects tree of you Tomcat in your Eclipse Server view. But it is possible to change the context path in your project properties at the Web Project Settings tab. However the path should be "http://localhost:port/[Eclipse project name]/rest/hello

Comment: shouldn't the @Path be "/rest/hello"? I never know, and just map the servlet to /* :-)

Comment: I don't think the "No provider classes found" is a fatal problem, or related to the 404 for the actual API requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue was resolved as follows. My localhost has been setup with "Apache" webserver which redirects all requests to Tomcat. Since "Jersey" is using a new servlet, I had to create a separate redirect for this servlet specifically.

In Linux

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

add:

```
JkMount /rest/* ajp13_worker
```

Comment: Are you sure this was due to httpd? Afterall, you were accessing http://localhost:8080/Jersey/rest/hello That means that apache2 was not redirecting and you were accessing tomcat directly. Can you please respond, as I am having the same 404 error and I am not having httpd running at all.

Answer (score 8):

Verify you have the right URL:

The tomcat manager application is happy to direct you to the root URL of the servlet. (you are assuming this is "Jersey" with capital J.)
http://localhost:8080/manager/html/list

Then you can skip the "rest" part by setting the URL pattern in the servlet mapping of the web.xml to "/*" (yes, there was a bug in Jersey related to that once, but that's ancient history)

Then you can append "application.wadl" to get a description of available resources. Theoretically:
http://localhost:8080/Jersey/application.wadl

Answer (score 1):

By default, Tomcat uses war file name or name of the top most directory of the exploded war as root context unless defined in catalina_home/conf/server.xml, catalina_home/conf/context.xml or in application's META-INF/context.xml file.

To access http://localhost:8080/Jersey/rest/hello, the context entry should be `<Context path="/Jersey" docBase="myapp"/>` and your resource should have `@Path("/rest/hello")`.

Comment: The @Path annotation that you have there is incorrect. The path specified by Path is relative to both the name of the servlet context and the servlet mapping. Your Path annotation would essentially map to http://localhost:8080/Jersey/rest/rest/hello.