# The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource in Rest web services

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

i am using restful webservices
I have a simple code as given below:

```
@Path("/v1/status")
public class ControllerServices 
{
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    String printOnly()
    {
        System.out.println("running successfully");
        return "<p>this webservice</p>";
    }


}
```

And my `web.xml` file goes like this:

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.techbloomer.services</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

When I request

```
http://localhost:8080/webservicesForIndTadka/rest/v1/status
```

it gives the error as

```
HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed
type: Status report
message: Method Not Allowed
description: The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
```

Comment: What is `com.techbloomer.services`?

Comment: What server are you using?

Maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585211/java-jersey-rest-no-provider-classes-found-404-error-when-accessing-url) can help you

Comment: How do you do he test request ? With a browser ? First idea: you do not do a GET request ...

Comment: In case you use FireFox as WebBrowser, you can install the `HttpFox` plugin which will sniff the HTTP request and response headers for you. --> Just for verification, how your request looks like. A further plugin called `RESTClient` will allow you to create custom HTTP requests.

Comment: @Xcito i am using vmware vfabric 2.8 server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Path("/v1/status")
public class ControllerServices 
{
    @GET
    @Path("print")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String printOnly()
    {
        System.out.println("running successfully");
        return "<p>this webservice</p>";
    }
}
```

The path annotation on the class indicates that this is a root resource class and the path value given specifies the base URI for all the web service methods contained in the class.

The @GET annotation is used to differentiate between a sub-resource method that handles the actual web service request and a sub-resource locator method that returns an object that will instead be used to handle the request. In this case, the method has the @GET annotation which means this method handles the request and returns the result.

If you navigate to `http://localhost:8080/webservicesForIndTadka/rest/v1/status/print/` you should see `printOnly` returning `"<p>this webservice</p>".`

Use FireFox and install [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/restclient/)

Comment: The @Path annotation on the WebService method isn't necessarily! So this maybe won't solve the problem.

Comment: Of course it's not necessary. It was only example code with explanation. But I do see in Mayur Guptas code that his webservice method is private. Can that be the problem?

Comment: I mean it should be `public String printOnly(){ ... }`

Comment: You are right! The method needs to be public. The service method in Mayur Gupta example is package private, which is not sufficient.

Comment: @Xcito , thanx for your help but still its not working .....
i just copy past your code...
it says: "The requested resource is not available."

Comment: @MayurGupta, this is the last thing I can think about without actually debugging the code. Try changing to `@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})`

Comment: @Xcito.. thanx xcito .. i appriciate your answers... if i got the solution i will notify you...

Comment: @Xcito i got the solution ... there was some incomplete name space in the xml file, including your point to make the service method public.
thanx.

Comment: @My-Name-Is thnx for pointing out the mistake. its working now.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a similar problem, when a GET request has a Content-Type in header, tomcat (version 7 in my case) returns error code 405.

Comment: How did you get around it ?

Comment: @JamesGawron You know, an HTTP GET request should not have content, so a Content-Type is useless, so I’ve removed this header from the client side.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your browser is sending a different content-type to the JAX-RS service.

Try

```
@Produces(
    {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML
    })
```

1. You should add

the following

```
@Path("/get")
```

for specifying the path to the method, JAX-RS may be using something different.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://localhost:8080/webservicesForIndTadka/rest/v1/status
```

I just had a similar problem and it boiled down to a missing / at the and of the request. In this case it would be

```
http://localhost:8080/webservicesForIndTadka/rest/v1/status/
```

Answer (score 0):

hi i have encountered the same problem but fixed it.

- use `@Path("pathName")` additional to your code.
- Run your project once in server.
- copy the url and paste it in your web-browser like chrome(i use chrome).
- http://localhost:8080/webservicesForIndTadka/rest/v1/status/pathName.
- `@Produces` may be optional sometimes.
- it may solve your problem.