# How to make this works embedded

Tags: maven, jersey, grizzly, embedded-server

I am combining [jax-rs HelloWorld example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8684442/743027) and [building executable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1814697/743027)

My expectation is to create this hello world with all dependencies inside one JAR file.

After extraction of heroku package I add this to the pom.xml (like described in second discussion + edit main class to just `Main`):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-beta-4</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

After that I build: `> mvn package`. I have my jar at : `target/jax-rs-heroku-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. I set PORT environment variable to 8080. I run the jar with:

```
>java -jar jax-rs-heroku-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Starting grizzly...
2013-08-29 15:33:27 com.sun.grizzly.Controller logVersion
INFO: Starting Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-i - Thu Aug 29 15:33:27 CEST 2013
Jersey started with WADL available at http://localhost:8080/application.wadl.
```

So far everything looking perfect! Now if I visit the page:

```
http://localhost:8080/application.wadl
```

Here real problem starts. Browser gives me an `Server error`. After visiting the page I have an exception in console log:

```
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  resources
2013-08-29 15:37:14 com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class resources.HelloResource
2013-08-29 15:37:14 com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
2013-08-29 15:37:14 com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9.1 09/14/2011 02:05 PM'
2013-08-29 15:37:14 com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorJAXBGrammarGenerator attachTypes
INFO: Couldn't find JAX-B element for class java.lang.String
2013-08-29 15:37:14 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse write
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream, and Java type class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream, and MIME media
type application/xml was not found
2013-08-29 15:37:14 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse write
SEVERE: The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter

2013-08-29 15:37:14 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream,
 and Java type class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream, and MIME media type application/xml was not found
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:285)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1437)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.FilterChainImpl.invokeFilterChain(FilterChainImpl.java:139)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.doService(ServletAdapter.java:376)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.service(ServletAdapter.java:324)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream, and Java type class java.
io.ByteArrayInputStream, and MIME media type application/xml was not found
        ... 27 more
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you upload the prj to github or something? it looks like you have some dependencies in the wrong scope.

Comment: Hi. The link is at first sentence of my Q. Here it is: https://github.com/jesperfj/jax-rs-heroku . Only modyfication to POM is posted in Q. After this approach failed I switched to Jetty. But I would be happy to do embedded Grizzly as well.