# Deploy Jersey web services in referenced .jar

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jar, jersey

I've created a .jar with some Jersey web services in it, and I want to import that .jar in other projects. Those web services work like a handler/proxy for local code to link with a remote service provider.

So, I import the .jar document in a project and configure `web.xml` like this:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Services</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.package.for.services.in.current.project, com.package.for.services.in.jar</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Services</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/s/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But when I run the project, the web services specified in `com.package.for.services.in.jar` aren't found.

The .jar document is in build path. What am I doing wrong? Isn't possible to run web services from an external library?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are u placing the jar containing jersey classes,  in your web container?

Comment: The .jar is in WEB-INF/lib, and then added to project's build path.

Comment: can u check on the server also whether it is in the WEB-INF/lib

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing.  I don't want to deploy the war every-time.  I can just restart the server and deploy the jar file

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from this post: [Jersey REST The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111074/jersey-rest-the-resourceconfig-instance-does-not-contain-any-root-resource-class)

The PackagesResourceConfig class depends on having a directory with the name of the package in order to find the classes within it. I went back to Eclipse, and found an option at the bottom of the **"Export ... > Jar"** dialog for **"Add directory entries."** I turned that on, exported the jar again, and then the scanning found my resource classes. You'll need to find some comparable option in your build environment.